# i keep getting 404 tomcat error

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I've wamp installed and working all fine using the port 80
I just installed tomcat apatche now to use Java EE and it keep getting the 404 tomcat error on my first project http://localhost:8080/test/ (a simple and empty html page) the server is [started,synchronised]
I've set the system variables as below

```
CATALINA_HOME for C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.24
JAVA_HOME for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51
```

and added  `;%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH`

it doesnt work
I've stopped the server, switched the server location to "use tomcat installation(take control of tomcat installation)"
and it didn't fix it either
I had tomcat a year before working but back then wamp wasn't installed
I'm really running out of options here . Anyone can help me please ?

Comment: I dont think  there is a relation between wamp and tomcat apart from port but you said you freshly installed it and dint change port so apache port would be 80 and tomcat would be 8080 .Before deploying your J2EE app you should check if tomcat path is correctly set or not what is output you are getting with `localhost:8080`?If the link gave you tomcat page then problem would be in your app url mappings in web.xml otherwise you have incorrect path

Comment: Indeed it's like you said
the output I'm getting with my localhost:8080 is the Tomcat 404 error page
so how can I fix the web.xml ? knowing that I only did a html page just as a start to check if everthing is working fine (i didnt touch anything else apart from the system variables which i kept having the 404 error page with or without them)

Comment: web.xml is the second part ie for running your web app first you have to check if tomcat is running if `localhost:8080` dint show anything or server dint start there may be 2 problem i can think first is path issue (if the above details of your path is the exact as you have then remove first `%JAVA_HOME%`) or any other application has acquired 8080 port which causing tomcat not to start

Comment: I imported my old project and it works !! so how come the new one doesnt ?! Or how can I find the issue comparing the two projects ? where do i look exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that indeed wamp is guilty. If it is running it listening to port 80, so tomcat cannot start listening to this port (if it is configured to do so in server.xml). So when you turn to localhost/test you actually arrive to wamp instead of tomcat.

So, first check whether wamp is running and what port tomcat is expected to listen to. Then either stop wamp or change the configuration of one of the severs to avoid ports conflict.

Take a look on the log files of tomcat. If it cannot start you can see some exceptions there.

Comment: Stop your web server, restart tomcat, see if you can reach your page.

Comment: tomcat is listening to 8080 port , wamp is listening to 80 port , as long as my tomcat server is on ,i get the Tomcat error page, and I get 0 error message, seems like all is working fine ,that's what confused me
the change is that I know have some log files on the apatche folder, which wasn't possible before I change the server locations to "use tomcat installation"

Comment: in the localhost_acess_log i get   127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jul/2015:19:25:45 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [23/Jul/2015:19:25:50 +0100] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1015

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I didn't have an *index.html* page.